# HTML parsing using Jsoup Java

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

```
 <select id="list">
 <option value="0">First</option>
 <option value="1">Second</option>
 <option value="2">Third</option>
 </select>
```

For the above html content how do I make use of Jsoup to parse and get the text as

```
  First Second Third
```

When I use

```
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(HTMLText);
String text=doc.text();
System.out.println(text);
```

I get something like this

```
FirstSecondThird
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already very close to the solution; just select the elements you need and get their text:

```
    final String html = " <select id=\"list\">\n"
            + " <option value=\"0\">First</option>\n"
            + " <option value=\"1\">Second</option>\n"
            + " <option value=\"2\">Third</option>\n"
            + " </select>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    String text = doc.select("option").text(); // Select all 'option' tags --> get text of them

    System.out.println(text);
```

Result:

```
First Second Third
```